# MNIST Neural Network Accuracy 0.0238 and very Random Losses

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Everytime I try to train this network, the loss keeps going farther negative. Like for step 1 to step 2 it goes down to like -230192809 and keeps going down. Also, the accuracy then ends up being 0.0238 or something. I have no idea what's happening. Since it keeps continually decreasing, I'm not sure whether that's a CPU issue or there's something wrong with the code that I have written below. If it is the code or the CPU/GPU, please let me know as I've been struggling with this for quite a while now. Thanks for the help!

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

old_v = tf.logging.get_verbosity()
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
train_data = mnist.train.images  # Returns np.array
train_labels = np.asarray(mnist.train.labels, dtype=np.int32)
eval_data = mnist.test.images  # Returns np.array
eval_labels = np.asarray(mnist.test.labels, dtype=np.int32)

tf.logging.set_verbosity(old_v)

n_nodes_hl1 = 500
n_nodes_hl2 = 500
n_nodes_hl3 = 500

n_classes = 10
batch_size = 100

# height by width
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 784))
y = tf.placeholder('float')


def neural_network_model(data):
    hidden_1_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, n_nodes_hl1])),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}

    hidden_2_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}

    hidden_3_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}

    output_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])),
                    'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hidden_2_layer['weights']), hidden_2_layer['biases'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, hidden_3_layer['weights']), hidden_3_layer['biases'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

    output = tf.add(tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weights']), output_layer['biases'])

    return output


def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=prediction, logits=y))

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    # cycles feed forward + backprop
    hm_epochs = 10

    with tf.Session() as sess:

        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            for _ in range(int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)):
                epoch_x, epoch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})
                epoch_loss += c
            print("Epoch", epoch, "completed out of", hm_epochs, " loss:", epoch_loss)

        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float32'))
        print("Accuracy: ", accuracy.eval({x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels}))


train_neural_network(x)
```

Comment: You have the logits and predictions mixed up in your loss calculation.

Comment: Thank you so much that was very helpful it fixed my problem right away